# Why does this compile command sequence keep creating a 64 bit file?

Tags: php, gcc, makefile, compilation, mamp

I'm using a mac OSX and trying to compile a binary from source.

the commands I'm using are

```
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/phpize CFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -Os' LDFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc ' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -Os' 
  ./configure --disable-dependancy-tracking --disable-shared -enable-static
  make
  make install
```

I've previously tried also including a number of other flags

-arch x86_64

and

```
 --with-php-config="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php-config"
```

but every time I check the compiled file it tells me that it's an x86_64 bundle.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding -m32 to the flags.  I doubt the optimization flags are making a difference here.

From the manual for gcc:

> ```
>    -m32
>    -m64
> ```
>
> Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment.  The 32-bit
>   environment sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits and generates code
>              that runs on any i386 system.  The 64-bit environment sets
>   int to
>              32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits and generates code
>   for
>              AMD's x86-64 architecture. For darwin only the -m64 option turns
>              off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options.

Comment: oh I have definitely tried adding -m32 but I put it inside CFLAGS etc... `CFLAGS='-O2 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -Os'` one thing I didn't try is putting it outside CFLAGS.  --- EDIT --- `/tmp/apd/apd-1.0.1: file /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apd.so 
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apd.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`  still getting 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried editing the Makefile immediately after running ./configure?  I agree with Mark's hypothesis that the flags are simply not being used.

Answer (score 2):

Random guess, possibly not correct.  Try setting `CC` instead.

```
CC="gcc -m32"
```

Edit:

Reason for my suggestion is that I don't know if CFLAGS is always respected in your build.

Comment: sadly, no.  It's still being a jerk `modules/apd.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`  I deleted the config.h, deleted the previous .so and ran phpize with just the CC= command and it's still coming out as 64 bit.  I wonder if there's some sort of weird path thing happening

Comment: Can you see the actual compilation output?  Can you verify that the changes are even occurring?

Answer (score 1):

After configuring, I edited the Makefile and changed the following:

CC = cc 
to
CC = cc -m32

And voila.